# cubic spline interpolation (cannot understand relevance of equidistant knots)

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I have to construct a cubic spline interpolating function with values given by this table [image]

During the construction we should take a note that we look for a spline with equidistant knots. Calculate the value of the spline at point 1.5

**Now I have done most of the work and came to conclusion of [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s3rmvgg0pk) being the cubic spline on each respective interval. I do not however understand the part with equidistant knots. (I know what equidistant knots are).**

Not sure how to tackle this "consideration". Thanks for any hits/check ups on the graph.